# Next 13.2 Image not found when running in Docker Container

Tags: docker, image, next.js

I built a docker container for a simple next js project; and when I try to use Image and access the files from under public -- it works in the local dev but in docker container I cannot find the image I get an exception. My docker file is a vanilla one from the documentation (with the output standalone)

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

FROM base AS deps
libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN
if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile;
elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci;
elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile;
else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1;
fi

FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN yarn build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
And the error I get are

Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/compiled/jest-worker'
Require stack:

/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/main.js
/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/image-optimizer.js
/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js
/app/server.js
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
at mod._resolveFilename (/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:23:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
at Object. (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/main.js:8:19)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
'/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/main.js',
'/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/image-optimizer.js',
'/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js',
'/app/server.js'
]
}
Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/compiled/jest-worker'
Require stack:
/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/main.js
/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/image-optimizer.js
/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js
/app/server.js
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
at mod._resolveFilename (/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:23:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
at Object. (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/main.js:8:19)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
I was able to resolve it by downgrading from NextJS 13.4.4 to 13.2.4.
I mentioned the same issue in the link below.

[Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/compiled/jest-worker' - On Docker #48173](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48173)

Below is the NextJS error message in the Docker container that occurred with NextJS 13.4.4.

[Captured NextJS error message in a Docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL2AP.png)

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078

  throw err;

  ^


Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/compiled/jest-worker'

Require stack:

- /usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/render-server-standalone.js

- /usr/src/app/server.js

    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)

    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)

    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)

    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)

    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/render-server-standalone.js:12:21)

    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)

    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)

    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)

    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)

    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19) {

  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

  requireStack: [

    '/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/render-server-standalone.js',

    '/usr/src/app/server.js'

  ]

}


Node.js v18.16.0
```

Comment: thank you for this -- thats what I ended up doing also